# Oracle database timestamp to timestamp with timezone

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Need help in inserting the data from timestamp , to timestamp with zone.

```
create table foo ( tswtz TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);

SQL:>insert into foo values(systimestamp)

TSWTZ                                 
---------------------------------------
09-08-16 11:39:21.199780000 AM +05:30 

create table foo1 (test_dt timestamp)

insert into foo1 values(systimestamp)
TEST_DT                        
--------------------------------
09-08-16 11:40:55.242754000 AM
```

Now , there is a scenario, where i need to insert the values of `foo1` to `foo`.
I have used the below command,

```
insert into foo (TSWTZ)  (select CAST(TEST_DT AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)  from foo1)
```

The select value displayed it as

```
09-08-16 11:40:55.242754000 AM ASIA/CALCUTTA
```

But it should display it as

```
09-08-16 11:40:55.242754000 AM +05:30.
```

Can you please help me on how to do that, without alter command ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your NLS parameters to get the result. Please read the oracle documentation as well [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm][1]

Try setting:

```
 NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
and NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
and NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT = HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
and NLS_TIME_FORMAT =   HH.MI.SSXFF AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns current time in time zone of your database server operating system, in your case `+05:30`.

When you cast from `TIMESTAMP` (without any time zone information) to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then Oracle takes your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` - unless you specify the time zone explicitly.

Obviously in your case the `SESSIONTIMEZONE` is set to `Asia/Calcutta`.

In order to get desired result you can do either

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '+05:30';
```

or

```
SELECT CAST((TEST_DT AT TIME ZONE '+05:30') AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) 
FROM ...
```

Note, time zone `Asia/Calcutta` is different than `+05:30`, although the offset is the same. Region names like `Asia/Calcutta` considers daylight saving times (which does not apply for Asia/Calcutta), UTC offsets like `+05:30` do not consider daylight saving times.